# Magento 2 describe attrubute property used in Plugin method

Tags: xml, configuration, plugin, di, around-plugin

I am trying to create a simple module and I can't find the propose of the attribute `name` and `type` inside the tag `type` and `plugin` in `di.xml`. 
can anyone describe attribute name used in plugin?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="???">
        <plugin name="???" type="???" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

The [documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/build/di-xml-file.html) is not so clear for a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<config>
    <type name="{ObservedType}">
      <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{PluginClassName}" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> You must specify these elements:

- `ObservedType`  : A class or interface which the plugin
  observes.(core file path)
- `pluginName` : An arbitrary plugin name that identifies a plugin.
  Also used to merge the configurations for the plugin.(you can set any
  unique name )
- `PluginClassName` : The name of a plugin’s class or its virtual type.
  Use the following naming convention when you specify this element:
  \Vendor\Module\Plugin\(extension file path in which you are overriding).

Answer (score 0):

A small explanation can be found here:

> https://mage2gen.com/snippets/plugin/

Besides that you can also generate Plugins, see the following example module:

> https://mage2gen.com/load/f268772e-c6b7-4b6d-83fa-b400824817d8

This example module contains the following di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_ModuleName_Plugin_Magento_Catalog_Model_Product" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\ModuleName\Plugin\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"/>
    </type>
</config>
```